# Making multi-column inline-block container to fit the contents width

Tags: javascript, css, multiple-columns, calculated-columns

I'm trying to create a horizontal layout of fixed height, inline-block elements that contain CSS columns in it.

```
article {
  -webkit-column-width: 200px;
  -moz-column-width: 200px;
  column-width: 200px;
  -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
  -moz-column-gap: 1em;
  column-gap: 1em;
  -moz-column-fill: auto;
  column-fill: auto;
  height: 350px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

The problem is that the width of inline-block elements is improperly set (columns take up less/more space than container provides) - it seems that the width corresponds to the content before it is being transformed into columns (in Chrome - in result containers are on top of each other) or fits single column (in Firefox and IE - in result containers overlap).

Example (inspect the width of article element):
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNQdVE

The only solution I came up with is to make container fit single column and use JS to set width to the scroll width. Is seems to work fine in all 3 browsers I tested.

Example:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpQNWg

Is there any pure CSS solution to this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding correctly, but You want your articles to line up side by side in a horizontal layout, unfortunately, they wrap when they get too long?  One solution that made them force side-by-side is to give your `body` a `white-space:nowrap;` css property.  Since all of your articles are `display:inline-block;` they are considered a span at that point.  `white-space:nowrap;` ensures all text will not wrap if it hits the end of a container

Comment: Yes, you understood it fine. I'm aware that i need to set `white-space:nowrap;' to prevent content form wrapping. The thing is that improper width of inline-block elements break the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the display from `inline-block` to `table-cell` seems to give you desired results.

Seen in this pen is that style applied along with borders for visual aid.

http://codepen.io/TheLarkInn/pen/jPQjzK

It appears that although it is an inline-block element, that the browser assumes the second column stretches the width of the viewport despite having a width of 300px per column.

You can also wrap all the articles in an element using `display: flex;` also.

Comment: I appears that you forgot to save your pen, and changing inline-block to table-cell doesn't do the trick. My primary goal is to make the containers horizontally scrollable (with unknown number of containers) so I cannot use flexbox.